# Get all-time-impressions for given contentName in Matomo Reporting API

Tags: matomo, piwiktracker

I'd like to request the core metrics for a given contentName in matomos reporting API. ContentName is in this example anwalt:4247, and I send this request:

```
https://statistics/?method=Contents.getContentNames&segment=contentName==anwalt:4247&label=anwalt:4247&date=2019-01-01,today&period=range&format=JSON&module=API&idSite=1&format=JSON&token_auth=93exx3
```

gives

```
[{"label":"anwalt:4247","nb_visits":27,"nb_impressions":37,"nb_interactions":12,"sum_daily_nb_uniq_visitors":27,"interaction_rate":"32,43\u00a0%","segment":"contentName==anwalt%3A4247","idsubdatatable":1}]
```

or this

```
https://statistics/?method=Contents.getContentNames&label=anwalt:4247&date=2019-01-01,today&period=range&format=JSON&module=API&idSite=1&format=JSON&token_auth=93exx3
```

gives

```
[{"label":"anwalt:4247","nb_visits":21,"nb_impressions":28,"nb_interactions":8,"sum_daily_nb_uniq_visitors":21,"interaction_rate":"28,57\u00a0%","segment":"contentName==anwalt%3A4247","idsubdatatable":282}]
```

But both numbers are wrong (other than in matomo UI).

Isn't there any simple request for that common task?

Answer (score 0):

What you tried with `&date=2019-01-01,today&period=range` should work fine, what is the problem in the output data?

Comment: The problem is, that the results of both requests are different - and also different from the results in the matomo - UI. So, whats the real number here?

Comment: sorry for late response. the numbers from API should always match the numbers in UI, because UI uses API exclusively